# Paypal developing - Unknown error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I use sandbox mode and get UNKNOWN_ERROR. My request (from developer.paypal.com):

```
{
    "body": {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "credit_card",
            "funding_instruments": [
                {
                    "credit_card": {
                        "first_name": "dfgdfg",
                        "billing_address": {
                            "phone": "435435435",
                            "postal_code": "54343",
                            "line1": "******",
                            "country_code": "AU",
                            "city": "rtytr"
                        },
                        "expire_month": 3,
                        "number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx4545",
                        "last_name": "dfgdfg",
                        "cvv2": "***",
                        "expire_year": 2021,
                        "type": "visa"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "invoice_number": "#",
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": "235.00",
                    "details": {
                        "subtotal": "235.00",
                        "tax": "0.00",
                        "shipping": "0.00"
                    }
                },
                "description": "descr...",
                "item_list": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "sku": "sku",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "price": "235.00",
                            "name": "Credits 5",
                            "quantity": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
        "x-pp-ads-performed": "false",
        "content-length": "624",
        "paypal-request-id": "44eae10f-64cb-43e6-b77e-74XXXXX56338",
        "x-pp-silover": "name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D4228306518",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "client-auth": "No cert",
        "authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmRN4",
        "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
        "user-agent": "PayPalSDK/PayPal-NET-SDK 1.7.3 (lang\\u003dDOTNET;v\\u003d4.5.1;clr\\u003d4.0.30319.42000;bit\\u003d64;os\\u003dMicrosoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)",
        "x-slr-orig-script_uri": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment",
        "x-pp-corrid": "2d94a472d94a2",
        "pp_remote_addr": "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-pp-slingshot-targetapp": "platformapiserv"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "method": "POST"
}
```

and response:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "duration_time": 4913,
    "body": {
        "message": "An unknown error has occurred",
        "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNKNOWN_ERROR",
        "name": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
        "debug_id": "2d94a472d94a2"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "header": {
        "Content-Length": "185",
        "Content-Language": "*",
        "CORRELATION-ID": "2d94a472d94a2",
        "Date": "Tue, 01 Mar 2016 21:17:53 GMT",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Paypal-Debug-Id": "2d94a472d94a2",
        "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\\u003dslcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId\\u003d369",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

I see debug-id, but don't know what I can do more with this value.
Any way to find more detail description of problem?